# Changing margins for first/last n lines on every page

Tags: geometry, border

I'm typesetting a multi-page text with a fancy frame on each page. As you can see on the attached picture, the inner corners of the frame are taking extra space and I would like to increase the margin for the first/last two lines (or for a certain distance from the top/bottom) on every page. Is there a simple way to do that?

[image: This is how the top of the page looks like right now]

Comment: this is very hard to do in tex as linebreaking happens before pagebreaking